# Is this a bash bug?

Tags: bash, echo

I met a strange string in bash.

```
    r=" * Animated Collapsible DIV v2.4- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)"
    echo $r
    le-linux-x86-20130219 aliedit.sh append5.sh append5.sh~ appendc6 appendc6~     appendc6.sh appendc6.sh~ appendc.sh appendc.sh~ append.sed append.sed~ append.sh append.sh~ argouml-0.34 azure.q99 cscope.out Desktop Documents dot1 dot1~ dot1.ps Download Downloads dump.mp3 DUMP.zip dynload_os2.c en-US Essential-English-Dictionary-v1.00riz-utf16.dsl.dz fi fileopen.pl first.perl flaim flaim (2) foo2zjs foo2zjs-patched.tar.gz foo2zjs.tar.gz glassfish-3.1.2.2 go go~ go1 go1~ go10 go10~ go11 go11~ go12 go12~ go13 go13~ go14 go14~ go15 go15~ go16 go16~ go17 go17~ go18 go18~ go2 go2~ go3 go3~ go4 go4~ go5 go5~ go6 go6~ go7 go8 go9 go9~ gogorender.plugin goldendict-1.0.1-src goldendict-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_GCC_32bit-Debug good google_appengine Google gp18 ib


    echo " * Animated Collapsible DIV v2.4- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)"
     * Animated Collapsible DIV v2.4- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
```

It puzzled me.

Comment: Try `echo "*"` and `echo *` to understand the difference in shell expansion.

Comment: For all the details: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug. When you typed

```
echo $r
```

echo received

```
* Animated Collapsible DIV v2.4- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
```

and replaced * with files from current directory.

Note that if you type
    r="many words"
the quotation marks are not in the variable r, they just limit its value.

Comment: Technically, the expansion of `*` is done by the shell before it runs `echo`, not by `echo` itself.